# Using ionic check-box

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im new to ionic and Im learning to use ion-check box, so I have a list of check-box with names. When the names are checked, they should be displayed on submission. I have tried the code but not sure the way i have used it correct

file.js:

```
var list= {};
list.name = new Array(7);
list.name [0]=  "John";
list.name [1] = "Krish";
list.name [2] = "Jessica";
list.name [3] = "Volizt";
```

controller.js:

```
    myApp.controller('myCtrl",function($scope)
   {
    $scope.names= list.name;
    $scope.submit=function()
    {
     $scope.finalList=[];
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.names.length;i++)
    {
     var item=names[i].checked;
      if(item.checked){
         $scope.finalList.push(item);
      }
     }
     }
   });
```

HTML:

```
 <ion-check ng-model="checkedNames" ng-change="selectedname()">
   <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all here is a good documentation:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionCheckbox/

you need a boolean for checkbox  so use like in the example

```
 $scope.names= [
    {name="John", checked=false},

    .
    .
    ]
```

if you have an array you need to loop like in the documentation

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="name in names"
                      ng-model="name.checked" 
                      ng-checked="name.checked">
          {{ name.name}}
        </ion-checkbox>
```

Second tip in general avoid spaces:

```
list.name [0]=  "John"; ->list.name[0]=  "John";
```

Third tip use angular for looping

```
angular.forEach($scope.names, function (name, index) {

});
```